# How to configure TASK_SERIALIZER with django-celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm using django-celery and I'd like to set the `TASK_SERIALIZER` to JSON instead of pickle.

I can do this on a per-method basis by changing my task decorators from

```
@task
```

to

```
@task(serializer="json")
```

But I'd like to do it globally.  Setting

```
TASK_SERIALIZER="json"
```

in `settings.py` doesn't work.  Trying to run

```
import celery
celery.conf.TASK_SERIALIZER="json"
```

(as implied [here](http://celeryproject.org/docs/reference/celery.conf.html)) results in

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'conf'
```

Any idea how to configure this setting when running celery through django?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Figured it out.

In `settings.py` you need to set

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
```

Docs are confusing, at least to me.

Answer (score 6):

I found that creating a celeryconfig file (like the docs recommend) makes things a lot cleaner.

celeryconfig.py

```
# Celery configuration file
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

You can sent set it with this command (once you call Celery)

```
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#isn-t-using-pickle-a-security-concern) :

> For the task messages you can set the CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER setting
>   to “json” or “yaml” instead of pickle. There is currently no
>   alternative solution for task results (but writing a custom result
>   backend using JSON is a simple task)

So setting `CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"` looks useless. In my case, results are still in pickle (Celery 3.1.3). Yeah. I know...

Comment: It looks like you can now specify a results serializer : http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-result-serializer - it would seem that other parts of the documentation have not been updated to reflect this.... pull request sent